# Ajax tool kit's AsyncFileUpload control is triggering dom ready

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asyncfileupload

I am using asp.net ajax tool kit's async file upload control on my page to upload images. It is working fine but on upload it is triggering jquery dom ready function which is totally redundant because it gets triggered once on page load and is also causing my other jquery plugins to break.

Any ideas why this is happening? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little tough to understand your problem with no HTML/ASP code provided. But as far as i think, Asnc file upload is as good as FileUpload placed in a update panel(Although it does not support that, that is why microsoft created asnc-file-upload control)
So as it is posting back it asynchronously, the EVent fired on DOM ready will not be applicable on it. An event of pageload is required here.
I'd suggest you to try writing the jquery code for the broken elements in pageLoad function like this

```
function pageLoad(sender,args){
   //write your code for broken elements here or simply copy paste everything from  $(document).ready in this function
}
```

If the above method does not work you can also tell the browser to perform actions when the ajax call has been completed like this

```
$( document ).ajaxStop( function() {
    //Do the needful here
});
```

Hope it helps...